# Angular 2 Get request not displaying first time

Tags: python, angular, typescript

I'm trying to populate Pie charts with information I get from a get request.

This is my service that does the get request to get a list of information

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BaThemeConfigProvider, colorHelper } from '../../../theme';
import { NodeService } from '../nodes.service';
@Injectable()
export class NodeService {
  constructor (
   private http: Http,
   ) {}

    getNodes() {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:5000/nodes`)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }

  }
```

And the following loads the information from that service and uses it to populate my pie charts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BaThemeConfigProvider, colorHelper } from '../../../theme';
import { NodeService } from '../nodes.service';


@Injectable()
export class PieChartService {

  constructor(private _baConfig: BaThemeConfigProvider, private nodeService: NodeService) {
  }
  profile = [];
  getData() {
    const pieColor = this._baConfig.get().colors.custom.dashboardPieChart;
    this.nodeService.getNodes().subscribe(data => this.profile = data,
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unnecessary-callback-wrapper
      error => alert(error),
     () => console.log('Finished with get request'),
     );
    const nodes = this.profile;
    const returnObject = [];
    const buildJsonObject = '';
    console.log('here', this.profile);
    for (const node of nodes) {
     const single_node = node;
     const buildJsonObject = '{ color: pieColor, description:' + single_node + '}';

     console.log(node);
     console.log(buildJsonObject);
     returnObject.push({ color: pieColor, description: single_node });
    }
    console.log('Final Object', returnObject);

    return returnObject;
  }
}
```

So the problem I'm having is that the first get request gets sent but it does not populate my charts but after the second request it gets populated with the first get requests information.

I am using a python server.

Comment: you are talking about  http.get() calling  two times instead of one  ?

Comment: no, it does the get request only once. But it only populates my pie charts after the second time i click on my pie charts tab

Comment: You are expecting an `async` request to be `sync`. That's not how it works.. That's not how any of this works :). Read in about handling async requests in TypeScript/JavaScript

Comment: Ok thank you. Im very new to angular :)